# How do you beat megadragonbowser?

Tags: mario-plus-rabbids-kingdom-battle

This is the ultimate boss of Mario+Rabbids kingdom battle. He replenishes his health when we do 1600 damage to him total then I see lava bucklers and there making all the heroes dead.What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of is killing enemies other than mega dragon bowser first this includes lava Valkyries, bucklers and smashers first. Because if I do megadragonbowser first than enemies on battlefield will just keep hitting the heroes until they are dead. Also avoid cover blocks and black char spots in the 2nd round because megadragonbowser breaths fire on those spots.In the 3rd round stay behind black blocks and avoid being close to a lava smasher because when megadragonbowser uses a shell and hit a black block he can’t use his shield until the next enemy turn when he does not hit a black block.